# dropzone при удаление файла появляется сообщение

Tags: javascript, dropzone

Dropzone.js. При удалении файла из области появляется это приветствие, мол перетащите файлы сюда. Как его отключить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нажимаю на удалить и появляется 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я понял там добавляются классы dropzone dz-clickable dz-started чтобы показать dz-message

понятное дело можно в ручную эти классы прописать, но как сделать все красиво, средствами dropzone, хотябы есть какие то спец функции события, чтобы отловить конец удаления и добавить классы

я на данный момент использую эту функцию

```
this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
  // .. ту т делаю удаление
  // при выходе из этой функции добавляются классы
  // где их отловить? может еще есть какой то хук хак ?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

стал копаться в исходном коде плагина, нашел событие reset
сделал такой код и все ок, окошко не всплывает

```
this.on("reset", function () {
  // .. ниче не делать)
});
```